# Can I use the laravel validator to ensure that items in an input array are unique?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Given four form fields, named as an array:

```
<input type="text" name="items[]">
<input type="text" name="items[]">
<input type="text" name="items[]">
<input type="text" name="items[]">
```

Is it possible to use the laravel validation class to ensure that each item value is unique?

I've tried:

```
$this->validate($request, [
    'items' => 'array|size:4|required',
    'items.*' => 'distinct'
]);
```

But the `items.*` portion doesn't seem to have any effect. What am I missing?

Edit: Here's the phpunit test I'm using:

```
$this->signIn();

$topic = create('App\tfTopic');

$this->post($topic->path().'/lists', ['items' => [
    "One is the loneliest number", 
    "One is the loneliest number",
    "Two is great", 
    "Three can be as bad as one" 
    ]])
    ->assertSessionHasErrors('items');
```

If I add to my controller:

```
dd(gettype(request('items')));
```

It dies with "array."

When I run the test, it fails with:

```
Session missing error: items
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

Comment: which field do you want to validate? try `items.*.id` if the id is unique

Comment: @tcPeng The fields are called "items[]" -- see the above example. It's just an array of strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your post test to this:

```
$this->post($topic->path().'/lists', ['items' => [
    "One is the loneliest number", 
    "One is the loneliest number",
    "Two is great", 
    "Three can be as bad as one" 
    ]])
    ->assertSessionHasErrors(['items.0', 'items.1']);
```

Comment: That's a typo (I'm writing this form as an example -- it's a phpunit test that's failing).

Comment: What happens if you test it manually? 
Post the phpunit error here.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this validation. Post your test here as well, that's probably where you have an issue.

Comment: That's it! The dot notation on the error message works. Your answer still has some discrepancies with 'items' and 'item' though.